# Are questions asking about a feature of controller emulators on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Are questions asking about **a feature of an emulator** solely be on-topic? According to the fourth bullet in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), "game-specific hardware and utilities" is on-topic. There is also a tag [emulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulator), which strengthens the hope of being accepted, but since I only use the controller to control my computer, not to play any game, I think it'd be better to ask here first.

Below is my sample question.

---

> ## What do the negative/positive throttles in the DS3 trigger buttons do?
>
> I have no idea what is the difference between the five options of throttles. In whatever choice only one button is triggerable, be it's pressed slightly or held long.
>
> [image]

Comment: It may help if you specify which emulator you're asking about

Comment: AntiMicro. Searching the site I only see it is mentioned once.

Comment: I will note that questions like this are often received negatively.  Try to be as descriptive as possible when asking a question like this (or any question really), but don't be surprised if it get's some down votes.

Comment: @TimmyJim as stated on the answer below, this kind of question is well received. Why do you think it will received negatively?

Comment: I think historically that these kind of questions have been shown (in recent times) to be received negatively.  That is probably due to the fact that most of the questions on emulators now a days are often low quality. 
 All but one link in the answer below are from 2012-2014.  I can tell you that back then, the users of the site were much different than today's current users.  I'm not saying that your question is 100% guaranteed to be received negatively.  If you put the effort into showing us what your problem is, you will likely be fine.

Comment: You've also taken the time to first bring it up on Meta to make sure it be an an on-topic and good question.  People like to see that.

Comment: @TimmyJim thanks. Do you know why does the quality of the questions go down, at least on this tag? Isn't the voting mechanism of Stack Exchange to prevent that, regardless of the user base?

Comment: Often people don't include screenshots and aren't descriptive enough about there problem.  That's what I mean for low quality.  You in this case have taken appropriate measures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Based on previous on-topic questions, I don't see any reason why questions about controller emulators wouldn't be allowed.**

---

[motioninjoy-ds3tool](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motioninjoy-ds3tool) (Dualshock 3 drivers which emulate an Xbox 360 controller)

- [When using my PS3 controller as a gamepad, how can I turn it off properly?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/46856/181240)
- [How can I stop getting BSoDs when using MotionInJoy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/72436/181240)
- [Panning with right analog stick in Skyrim (PC) with ps3 controller](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/50910/181240)

[xpadder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xpadder) (Xbox 360 controller emulator)

- [How can I use my gamepad trackball with Crysis 2 and Xpadder?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/82803/181240)
- [Can I run Xpadder with a specific profile at launch?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/312426/181240)
- [Controller always pulls left in Need for Speed: Most Wanted (2005)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/155738/181240)

Emulator-specific features

- [Does the Dolphin Emulator Support 3DTV Output?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/103071/181240)
- [Can I switch RetroArch's GBC core from gambatte to mednafen?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/136552/181240)
- [How to add more ROMs to MAME on X-Arcade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/114966/181240)

Comment: Thanks, I've asked my questing here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/315350/95533